# How to multiply all the columns of my table (excel or R data frame) with a scalar where each cell contains a character as well?

Tags: r, excel

I have a table (Excel table or R dataframe) like this:

```
Taxa    Pathway_1474    Pathway_1510    Pathway_1524    Pathway_197 Pathway_246
Acidaminococcus_intestini   d:-0.00350192996982 c:0.00222850088988  d:-1.66533453694e-18    d:-0.00254685815987 c:0.0019101436199
Acinetobacter_ursingii  b:0.0   b:-0.0019101436199  a:0.00413864450979  a:0.0057304308597   a:0.000636714539967
Actinomyces_odontolyticus   b:0.0   b:0.0   b:0.0   b:-0.000318357269984    b:0.0
Actinomyces_sp_HPA0247  d:0.0   d:0.0   d:-0.000636714539967    c:0.0038202872398   d:-0.000636714539967
Actinomyces_sp_ICM47    d:0.0   d:0.0   d:0.0   c:0.000318357269984 d:0.0
```

I want to multiply all the columns (except the first "Taxa" column) with (-1). But, I am unable to do so as each cell also contains character like a:, b:, etc. How can I do that keeping those chrarcters as well. The output should look like this:

```
Taxa    Pathway_1474    Pathway_1510    Pathway_1524    Pathway_197 Pathway_246
Acidaminococcus_intestini   d:0.00350192996982  c:-0.00222850088988 d:1.66533453694e-18 d:0.00254685815987  c:-0.0019101436199
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I do this? Any help in the context of Excel or R dataframe will be accepted.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2:** the promised shorter version of the same code:
How it works:
After removing the `character` column which we generated with the `separate` function, by adding `.keep="unused"` to mutate before `pivot_wider` we can omit all code after `pivot_wider`.

```
df %>% 
    pivot_longer(
        -Taxa,
        names_to = "names",
        values_to = "values"
    ) %>% 
    separate(values, c("character", "values"), sep = ":") %>% 
    mutate(values = as.numeric(values)*-1,
           values = paste(character, values, sep = ":"), .keep="unused") %>% 
    pivot_wider(
        names_from = names,
        values_from = "values"
    )
```

Output:

```
Taxa                      Pathway_1474       Pathway_1510   Pathway_1524  Pathway_197  Pathway_246 
  <chr>                     <chr>              <chr>          <chr>         <chr>        <chr>       
1 Acidaminococcus_intestini d:0.00350192996982 c:-0.00222850~ d:1.66533453~ d:0.0025468~ c:-0.001910~
2 Acinetobacter_ursingii    b:0                b:0.001910143~ a:-0.0041386~ a:-0.005730~ a:-0.000636~
3 Actinomyces_odontolyticus b:0                b:0            b:0           b:0.0003183~ b:0         
4 Actinomyces_sp_HPA0247    d:0                d:0            d:0.00063671~ c:-0.003820~ d:0.0006367~
5 Actinomyces_sp_ICM47      d:0                d:0            d:0           c:-0.000318~ d:0         
>
```

**Update: after clarification:**
How it works:

1. bring to long format with `pivot_longer`
2. `separate` the `values` column by `:`
3. multiply `values` by -1 and add the character to this column.
4. bring into wide format again with `pivot_wider`
5. using `purrr`s `map` and `nest` and `unnest` from `tidyr` to merge the rows within groups and remove the NA.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    pivot_longer(
        -Taxa,
        names_to = "names",
        values_to = "values"
    ) %>% 
    separate(values, c("character", "values"), sep = ":") %>% 
    mutate(values = as.numeric(values)*-1,
           values = paste(character, values, sep = ":")) %>% 
    pivot_wider(
        names_from = names,
        values_from = "values"
    ) %>% 
    select(-character) %>% 
    nest(-Taxa) %>% 
    mutate(data = map(data, ~ map_dfc(., na.omit))) %>% 
    unnest()
```

Output:

```
  Taxa                      Pathway_1474       Pathway_1510  Pathway_1524  Pathway_197  Pathway_246 
  <chr>                     <chr>              <chr>         <chr>         <chr>        <chr>       
1 Acidaminococcus_intestini d:0.00350192996982 c:-0.0022285~ d:1.66533453~ d:0.0025468~ c:-0.001910~
2 Acinetobacter_ursingii    b:0                b:0.00191014~ a:-0.0041386~ a:-0.005730~ a:-0.000636~
3 Actinomyces_odontolyticus b:0                b:0           b:0           b:0.0003183~ b:0         
4 Actinomyces_sp_HPA0247    d:0                d:0           d:0.00063671~ c:-0.003820~ d:0.0006367~
5 Actinomyces_sp_ICM47      d:0                d:0           d:0           c:-0.000318~ d:0
```

**First answer:**
We could use `across` from `dplyr` and `parse_number` from `readr` both are loaded with `tidyverse`:

1. `mutate` over all columns that start with `Pathway` and extract the numbers only.
2. `mutate` again over all now `numeric` )alternatively you can use `starts_with("Pathway")`) and multiply by -1

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    mutate(across(starts_with("Pathway"), parse_number),
           across(where(is.numeric), ~ .x * -1))
```

```
                       Taxa Pathway_1474 Pathway_1510  Pathway_1524   Pathway_197   Pathway_246
1 Acidaminococcus_intestini   0.00350193 -0.002228501  1.665335e-18  0.0025468582 -0.0019101436
2    Acinetobacter_ursingii   0.00000000  0.001910144 -4.138645e-03 -0.0057304309 -0.0006367145
3 Actinomyces_odontolyticus   0.00000000  0.000000000  0.000000e+00  0.0003183573  0.0000000000
4    Actinomyces_sp_HPA0247   0.00000000  0.000000000  6.367145e-04 -0.0038202872  0.0006367145
5      Actinomyces_sp_ICM47   0.00000000  0.000000000  0.000000e+00 -0.0003183573  0.0000000000
```

Comment: Hi TarJae... thanks for your time. But, the output should also contain the initial character as well. I mean like this `d:0.00350192996982`

Comment: Thanks a lot TarJae. But, it is showing me the warning message. Should I ignore this message or this is a serious one?  `Warning messages:
1: All elements of `...` must be named.
Did you want `data = c(Pathway_1474, Pathway_1510, Pathway_1524, Pathway_197, Pathway_246, 
    Pathway_258, Pathway_511, Pathway_560, Pathway_761, Pathway_762, 
    Pathway_900)`? 
2: `cols` is now required when using unnest().
Please use `cols = c(data)``

Comment: you can add the colnames you want to unnest or you can just ignore. It is showing to improve your style and for future directions. But I am working on a shorter code for your solution. The long one is also interesting just to learn how things work!

Comment: So, you mean the process will not change the column names or the row names and everything will be kept intact except for the signs (plus and minus). Right?

Comment: Yes! It will change nothing else.

Comment: Thanks a lot, TarJae for the complete explanation. It works.

Comment: Please see my Update2. Here the code is shorter and more handy!

Comment: Thanks a lot, TarJae. In addition, can you please tell me how can I flip the position of `a` and `c` and also flip the position of `b` and `d`?

Comment: What do you mean flip `a` and `c` only the letters eg. within one column e.g. `Pathway_1524`: `a:-0.005730` to `c:-0.005730` ... or the whole row.. Maybe is best when you define it in a new question?!

Answer (score 0):

I would take the number and drop the first two characters - such as the “d:”.

This is one approach:

```
=right(B1,len(B1)-2
```

If the number of characters varies then you can use find() to get the position of the colon :

Answer (score 0):

I´m sorry, but I have Excel in spanish. Writing `=EXTRAE(B2,3,LARGO(B2)-2)*-1` in Excel in spanish solves your problem. I think that in english is `=MID(B2,3,LEN(B2)-2)*-1`.

In R is

```
as.numeric(substr(df$Pathway_1474,3,nchar(df$Pathway_1474))) * -1
```

and you can loop for all the columns that are not the Taxa column (the first column) of your dataframe with

```
# Import the table
df = openxlsx::read.xlsx(xlsxFile = "path/file.xlsx")

# Generate new columns you want
for(i in 2:ncol(df)){
    df[[paste0(colnames(df)[i],"_New")]] = paste0(substr(df[[i]],1,2),as.numeric(substr(df[[i]],3,nchar(df[[i]]))) * -1)
}
```

Then you'll have the next dataframe

```
#                       Taxa        Pathway_1474       Pathway_1510         Pathway_1524          Pathway_197          Pathway_246   Pathway_1474_New    Pathway_1510_New    Pathway_1524_New      Pathway_197_New
#1 Acidaminococcus_intestini d:-0.00350192996982 c:0.00222850088988 d:-1.66533453694e-18  d:-0.00254685815987    c:0.0019101436199 d:0.00350192996982 c:-0.00222850088988 d:1.66533453694e-18   d:0.00254685815987
#2    Acinetobacter_ursingii               b:0.0 b:-0.0019101436199   a:0.00413864450979    a:0.0057304308597  a:0.000636714539967                b:0   b:0.0019101436199 a:-0.00413864450979   a:-0.0057304308597
#3 Actinomyces_odontolyticus               b:0.0              b:0.0                b:0.0 b:-0.000318357269984                b:0.0                b:0                 b:0                 b:0  b:0.000318357269984
#4    Actinomyces_sp_HPA0247               d:0.0              d:0.0 d:-0.000636714539967    c:0.0038202872398 d:-0.000636714539967                d:0                 d:0 d:0.000636714539967   c:-0.0038202872398
#5      Actinomyces_sp_ICM47               d:0.0              d:0.0                d:0.0  c:0.000318357269984                d:0.0                d:0                 d:0                 d:0 c:-0.000318357269984
```

and to save the dataframe as an excel try

```
openxlsx::write.xlsx(df, file = "path/newfile.xlsx")
```

`openxlsx` is an excelent package for importing and exporting excel files.

Comment: Thanks Alejo, I am new in R. Can you please tell me how can I save the output fro this loop? Also, the character and the colon should also be in the output like: `d:0.00350192996982`

Comment: if you have imported the Excel table to R into the `df` variable. Only by running the for loop will generate the new columns. `colnames(df)[i]` returns the column name in the index i, and with `paste0` function you concatenate strings next to each other. I edited the answer in the `paste0` function part for a more propper name of the new column.

Comment: Yes, Alejo- But it does not has the character part. I mean the `a:`, `b:`, `c:`, `d:` part is removed

Comment: I edited the answer with the code to import , generate the new columns and export the dataframe as an .xlsx file.

Comment: Done. Again, with `substr` and `paste0` functions you can extract substrings from strings and concatenate strings.

Comment: Tha `a:` `b:` `c: `and `d:` part is also solved with base R.